Blender image textures are only visible when in texture paint, but disappear when in any other mode
I found some questions similar to my problem, but the answer hadn't clear for me as a new Blender user.
I made a cylinder to create chimney model and UV unwrapped it with an image in the UV editor. I use image textures wrangler node and they show up, but dissapear after I go to another mode than texture paint and solid preview.
At material preview and render preview it will show just black cylinder.
And if I export to FBX, it will show in base color instead of image color I had set.
Do I mistake in a setting ?

Here are the screenshoots of my simple cylinder :





Hello, are you sure that the Image Texture is plugged into the Base Color of your Principled BSDF? Maybe pack your image and share your object?

In the top right corner of the 3D Viewport, the arrow next to the 4 spheres, if you open that menu and change the option under Color to Texture, that should fix it in Solid view. Also if you're in Rendered mode but don't have any lights in the scene then your object will appear black.


In viewport shading, click the arrow and check if texture selected for color.

In object properties, viewport display, make sure display as is set to textured.


